# Why a student is not edited

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I wrote a project where you can add and edit students. I have a list of students, all functions work except editing. I want to change the name and surname, avatar student, but does not work. Can see the code, I think I wrote everything correctly, why the function for editing a student does not work

Student Controller

```java
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }

        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }

}
```

Edit Student JSP

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <center>
                <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>


                <form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>
                        <input type="hidden" value="${student.id}" name="id"/>
                        <tr>

                            <td><label path="Name">Name</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="${student.name}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Surname">Surname</label></td>
                            <td><input name="surname" value="${student.surname}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Avatar">Avatar:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar?avatar=${student.avatar}"
                                     style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form:form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Student Service

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.service;
import java.util.List;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public interface StudentService {

    List<Student> getAllStudents();

    Student getStudentById(Long id);

    boolean saveStudent(Student student);

    boolean deleteStudentById(Long id);

    File loadAvatarByFileName(String filename);

    File saveAvatarImage(MultipartFile avatarImage) throws IOException;

        Student updateStudent(String name, String surname, MultipartFile avatar, Student targetStudent) throws IOException;
}
```

Student Service Impl

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.repository.StudentRepository;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;



@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Value("${storage.location}")

    private String storageLocation;

    private StudentRepository repository;

    public StudentServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentServiceImpl(StudentRepository repository) {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(e -> list.add(e));
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudentById(Long id) {
        Student student = repository.findById(id).get();
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveStudent(Student student) {
        try {
            repository.save(student);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteStudentById(Long id) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override

    public File loadAvatarByFileName(String filename) {

        return new File(storageLocation + "/" + filename);

    }

    @Override


    public File saveAvatarImage(MultipartFile avatarImage) throws IOException {

        File newFile = File.createTempFile(
                avatarImage.getName(),
                "." + avatarImage.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[1],

                new File(storageLocation));

        avatarImage.transferTo(newFile);

        return newFile;

    }

    @Override

    public Student updateStudent(String name, String surname, MultipartFile avatar, Student targetStudent)

           throws IOException {

        if (name != null && !name.equals(targetStudent.getName())) {

            targetStudent.setName(name);

        }

        if (surname != null && !surname.equals(targetStudent.getSurname())) {

            targetStudent.setSurname(surname);

        }

        String oldAvatarName = targetStudent.getAvatar();

        if (oldAvatarName != null) {
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(storageLocation + File.separator + oldAvatarName));
        }

        File newAvatar = null;
        if (avatar != null) {
            newAvatar = saveAvatarImage(avatar);
            assert newAvatar != null;
            targetStudent.setAvatar(newAvatar.getName());
        }

       boolean isSaved = saveStudent(targetStudent);

        if (!isSaved) {

            throw new IOException();

        }

        Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(storageLocation + File.separator + oldAvatarName));

        return targetStudent;

    }


}
```

I add Student repository

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long>{

}
```

Comment: What does updateStudent do?

Comment: Impossible to tell what's wrong, without seeing the code for `StudentService`.

Comment: Updates student data (name, surname,avatar)

Comment: I add Student Service code

Comment: Your `updateStudent` method doesn't appear to touch the repository.  Somehow, it feels to me like it should.

Comment: How can I fix ???

Comment: Not sure if this will help, and this comes from JPA, but there is something called `saveAndFlush` that you may have to call if you want to see the changes reflected in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

From the StudentServiceImpl updateStudent code, I can see that you didn't touch the repository, once you have updated the values for the existing student by update method you have to save the updated value with repository.save(object), you have done some db actions using the repository, so you have to save the updated object to db.

Comment: Try 
repository.save(targetStudent);
it will update the value

Comment: In updatestudent code before returning the targetStudent do the above step